# Workflow handling on Camunda engine restart

Tags: camunda

Scenario : Few jobs are running currently. If cluster reboot happens in the middle of the job execution, I shall be able to observe the continuity of process instance execution with proper state after reboot.

Will Camunda take care of preserving the process instance state by using some checkpoints and resumes automatically from where it halted ?

Comment: Camunda does commit at certain node types (timer, message , event gateway, async continuations etc). It is up to the use case bpmn model to model it in a correct way . Check out : http://docs.camunda.org/latest/guides/user-guide/#process-engine-transactions-in-processes-transaction-boundaries

Answer (score 0):

If you have reached at least one asynchronous continuation (e.g. check the property "async after" or on the start event), then the process instance has been persistent to the database and a job scheduled. Any crash would lead the following transaction to not commit and rollback. The job executor will restart processing from the last commit point when it detects a due job.